# Interpolating points with minimum curvature constraint

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, discrete-geometry, reference-request

I have $n$ points $p_i$ strictly interior to a rectangle $R$,
and I would like to connect them with a curve $C$ whose curvature is as low as possible.
Let $\kappa_\max(C)$ be the sharpest (largest absolute value) of the curvature of $C$
at any point along $C$.
More specifically, $C$ should:
(a) pass through the points *in any order*;
(b) be simple, i.e., non-self-intersecting;
(c) remain inside $R$;
and (d) have the minimum $\kappa_\max(C)$ over all $C$ satisfying
(a,b,c).

For example, perhaps the curve left below is optimal.
(*Later*: It's not; see below.)
The right curve has lower curvature but strays exterior to $R$.

          
[image]

I am seeking a lower bound on the minimum of $\kappa_\max$,
as a function of the point configuration and its placement within $R$.
I have seen literature bounding curvature *variation*, 
and literature focused on *shortest paths* of bounded curvature,
and literature that permits $C$ to self-cross,
but no literature on my specific collection of constraints.
My $n$ is not large, so a solution for a fixed permutation
would still be quite useful.
If anyone can point me to relevant literature, I would appreciate it.
Thanks!

**Addendum**. Here is what I gather must be Anton Petrunin's idea:

                    
[image: BoundedCurvature]
And here is Scott Carnahan's improvement to my example, left:

                    
[image: Improvement]

Comment: Note that if your points lie in an annulus $B_x(R)\backslash B_y(r)$ then $\kappa_{{\max}}\ge \tfrac1r$.

Comment: @Anton: Thanks!  However, if the points in the annulus happen to lie on a nearly
collinear arc, they could be captured by that low-curvature arc.

Comment: Ups, I wanted to say $\kappa_\max\le \tfrac1r$.

Comment: Oh, OK--Nice! $\mbox{}$

Comment: You might be interested in questions 19074 and 22601 as well as some
of the answers given to them even though the sort of minimizing curve sought for in these questions is of the "y=f(x)" type. With
regard to your question, it occurs to me that if your curve C was
the arc of a spiral enclosing a sufficiently large portion of the
Euclidean plane, the maximum absolute value of its curvature at any
point might be made arbitrarily small while all your n points could still be points of C. Of course this would violate your condition
(c) unless your rectangle R was large enough.


Comment: @Garabed: Thanks for those related MO questions.  Yes, it is the rectangle that is spoiling that approach.

Comment: It looks to me like the ordering 5-4-2-1-3 could yield a lower curvature path.  In particular, it might be best to avoid points of inflection whenever possible.

Comment: take a look at http://levien.com/phd/LevienSequinCAD09_014.pdf 

Comment: Is it really *pointwise* curvature you want to minimize, or *total curvature* (the integral of the pointwise curvature wrt arc length)?   If it's just pointwise curvature, why not just connect up pairs of points on great circles passing through infinity on the complex plane, and then use very gradual spirals to merge one great circle into another?   Do you want the curve to be embedded or is immersed enough?   Because I think if you're okay with immersed curves and are only constraining the pointwise max curvature, you should be able to approximate 0 curvature. 

Comment: Ah, I missed your non-self-intersecting constraint. 

Comment: @Scott: You are right! Added a corresponding image. @Ryan: Remaining inside $R$ eliminates many options. @Will: Thanks for the relevant link! Their focus is aesthetics, but still there are many ideas in there I might use.


Comment: Concerning the box constraint: It seems three points close to three distinct corners forces high curvature, as only two of those points can be curve endpoints.